# Wrapfig in poster environment

Tags: wrapfigure, posters

Specifically I'm using   the https://www.overleaf.com/articles/an-initial-analysis-of-approximation-error-for-evolutionary-algorithms/kgkpjgxzywjq  template
I added \usepackage{wrapfig} to the environment, but I still get the error environment wrapfig undefined

%% Author: Jun He
%% Date: 2017.05.11
% designed by Jun He on 11 May 2015
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer} 

%\usepackage[orientation=portrait,scale=1.1,size=a0]{beamerposter}  
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,scale=0.875,size=a1]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage{aber} %my own defined style
\usetheme{Frankfurt} 
\usecolortheme{whale}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usecolortheme{crane}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={thick}} 
 
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{wrapfig}  %%added
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{aber1.jpg}} %insert background photo
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{institute}{fg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=white} 
 
\title{{\Huge An Initial  Analysis of Approximation Error for Evolutionary Algorithms}} % Poster title
\author{\Large Jun He \inst{1} \and Yuren Zhou \inst{2} \and Guangming Li \inst{3}}
\institute{\normalsize   \inst{1}Aberystwyth University, UK \,\, \inst{2} Sun Yat-sen University, China\,\, \inst{3} Shenzhen Institute of Information Technology, China}
 
%% own commands
\newcommand{\opt}{\mathrm{max}} 
\newcommand*{\defeq }{:=}  

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]  
\maketitle

\begin{columns}[t]  
\begin{column}{0.45\paperwidth} 
%%%%%%%%%%% Start of Column 1 %%%%%%%%%%

\begin{greenblock}{Motivation}
This work aims at rigorously analyzing the approximation error of evolutionary algorithms (EAs). 
\end{greenblock}

\begin{greenblock}{Background}
Consider an EA for solving a maximization problem:
\begin{align}
\max f(x), \mbox{ subject to } x \in \mathcal{S}.
\end{align}

Let  $f_{\opt}$ denote the fitness of the optimal solution and $F_t$  the expected  fitness of the best solution  found  in the $t$th generation. 

\begin{definition}{Definitions}
\begin{itemize}
\item The \textbf{approximation error} of the EA in the $t$th generation is   
\begin{equation}
E_t:=f_{\opt}-F_t.
\end{equation}   
\begin{wrapfig}{r}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{figs/aber1.jpg}
\end{wrapfig}
\item If some positive constants
$\alpha$ and $\beta$ exist with
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to +\infty} \frac{E_t}{(E_{t-1})^{\alpha}}  =\beta,
\end{align}   then $\{E_t; t=0,1, \cdots\}$ is called to \textbf{converge to $0$ in the order $\alpha$}, with \textbf{asymptotic error constant $\beta$}~\cite{burden2015numerical,gautschi2011numerical}. 

\end{itemize}

\end{definition} 

\end{greenblock}
```

rest of code is same as in https://www.overleaf.com/articles/an-initial-analysis-of-approximation-error-for-evolutionary-algorithms/kgkpjgxzywjq

Also I have found that text doesn't wrap very well around pictures in the poster environment is there a way to fix that?

Comment: It is more a matter of using wrapfig around equations and itemize.  You can always use minipages and manually break the paragraphs.  Search for \nopar and \splitpar.

Comment: You MWE is not executable, both due to aber.sty and a whole lot of missing \end macros.